# Error with oracle database creation

Tags: database, oracle11g

I'm totally a newbie with Oracle, I've basically understood the basis but I've encountered many issues in installing the SW on my pc. I'm using a windows 8 computer.
Instead the installation on the computer of my friend has been quite simple.

At the end of all, I was able to install the software, but the database was not created. So I have tried to do it manually from command line.
Now I am able to connect to sqlplus (even it Enterprise Manager still not work) but in sqlplus I can't do nothing because I receive always the same errors.
For ex., if a query "SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM USER_TABLESPACES;" I receive error ORA01219 Database not opened
Then, with "ALTER DATABASE OPEN" i receive error ORA01507 Database not mounted
Then, if I try to mount the db with "ALTER DATABASE MOUNT" I receive the error ORA00205 error in identifying control file
Then with "SHOW PARAMETERS control_files" I receive the path of the files, but these file does not really exist.
I think they have not been created during the installation process, I've a really basic knowledge of the issue...
I hope someone can help me, so when I'll the get the db working I will start to train my self...
Thanks a lot in advance,
Peace.

Comment: Did you create your database? You have to use dbca utility for that. After that you need to open sqlplus as SYSDBA and enter command `STARTUP`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Database Configuration Assistant (DBCA) instead of `CREATE DATABASE...`.  DBCA has a GUI wizard that takes you through all the steps.  As you've discovered, installing and configuring Oracle is not simple, there's no shame in using the GUI at first.